# Azure Cloud Shell history persist across sessions

Tags: azure, shell, cloud

My Azure Cloud Shell history does not persist across sessions (which time out after 10 mins so this is annoying). The `.bashrc` has

```
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

So this should work, but no `.bash_history` gets written.

Comment: What is your Linux type? Ubuntu or other?

Comment: What is the current shell you use? You could check `echo $SHELL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you description, it seems that your shell environment variable does not set correctly. I test on my Azure VM, it works for me. I suggest you could check as the following methods.

1.Check you current shell.

You could use `echo $SHELL` to get your current shell. `.bashrc` profile is used for bash shell. If you use other shell, such as csh, it does not work.

2.Check `.profile` file. Please ensure the following commands are existing.

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

3.Check `.profile` and `.bashrc` user and group permission.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 shui shui 3771 Aug 31  2015 .bashrc
```

Update:

Cloud Shell does not save history command to `.bash_history`. If you want to do this. You could add `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` to `.bashrc`. Such as belwo:

```
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

Then you could `source .profile`. Now, you could find `.bash_histroy` and store your latest history command.

Notes: It is not recommended to do this, because other people could see you command, this is unsafe behavior.

Comment: Hi - this is not a shell in a VM - it is the Cloud Shell. Thanks!

Comment: @Gaius Thanks for you reply, I test in my lab, I could get `.bash_history` file. Could you get history command with `history`?

Comment: Only within the same session, which times out after 10 mins.

Comment: @Gaius Sorry for my mistake, now, I know the reason. By default, Cloud Shell does not save history commands to `.bash_history`. If you want to do this, just add `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` to `.bashrc`. I updated it to my answer. You could check it.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi Walter, I tried that and now my Cloud Shell doesn't work at all, `az vm start` just hangs and the status doesn't change in the GUI either so I don't think it's doing anything

Comment: @Gaius It is very strange. `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` add to `.bashrc` file could record the latest command. It works for me. I only add the command.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, bash history is written out on a successful exit of the bash process. In case of a premature timeout (increased to 20 minutes now), a history is not getting written out. It's a bug they are working on to fix.